# How to add the variable value to <td> with append?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I would like to display the numbers from 0 to 224 on each square. The squares are build and I can see the numbers on the console but they don't show the value of the variable "x"

```js
function buildBricks2() {
  let boardSide = 14;
  let table = $('<table>');
  let tbody = table.append('<tbody />').children('tbody');
  for (let i = 0; i <= boardSide; i++) {
    tbody.append('<tr />')
    for (let j = 0; j <= boardSide; j++) {
      let x = console.log(indexOfTile(i, j))

      tbody.append('<td />');
      $('td').append(x);
    }
  }
  table.appendTo('#board2');
}
buildBricks2();

function indexOfTile(row, column) {
  var boardLen = 15;
  if (row < boardLen && row >= 0 && column < boardLen && column >= 0) {
    return row * boardLen + column;
  } else {
    return -1;
  }
};
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="board2"></div>
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GpO8m.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is because you use `$('td')` to select all the `td` elements which exist in the DOM, however at the point you execute that line of code there are no `td` in the DOM as you've not yet appended them. They only exist in memory.

The simplest way to fix this is to amend your code to set the text of the `td` at the point you create it.

Also note that you're setting `x` to the value returned from `console.log()` which is not correct. I presume this is just a typo from your testing and not an actual issue

```
for (let j = 0; j <= boardSide; j++) {
  let x = indexOfTile(i, j);
  $('<td />', { text: x }).appendTo(tbody);
}
```

In addition there's a few tweaks which can be made to make the logic more performant and succinct. Here's a full example:

```js
function buildBricks2() {
  let boardSide = 14;
  let $table = $('<table>');
  let $tbody = $('<tbody />').appendTo($table);
  
  for (let i = 0; i <= boardSide; i++) {
    let $tr = $('<tr />').appendTo($tbody);
    for (let j = 0; j <= boardSide; j++) {
      let x = indexOfTile(i, j);
      $('<td />', { text: x }).appendTo($tr);
    }
  }
  
  $table.appendTo('#board2');
}
buildBricks2();

function indexOfTile(row, column) {
  var boardLen = 15;
  if (row < boardLen && row >= 0 && column < boardLen && column >= 0) {
    return row * boardLen + column;
  } else {
    return -1;
  }
};
```

```css
td {
  border: 1px solid black;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="board2"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Basically, you're not setting the text of the `<td>`.  Take a look:  Before you had simply `<td/>` being appended.  This is a blank cell.  You need to append the cell with the data that should be appended: `tbody.append('<td>' + x + '</td>');`.

***Also:*** You have `let x = console.log(indexOfTile(i, j))`.  To be clear, this is not setting x to the value of `indexOfTile(i, j)`, so, I have also fixed this in the code below.

Works now:

```js
function buildBricks2() {
  let boardSide = 14;
  let table = $('<table>');
  let tbody = table.append('<tbody />').children('tbody');
  for (let i = 0; i <= boardSide; i++) {
    tbody.append('<tr />')
    for (let j = 0; j <= boardSide; j++) {
      let x = indexOfTile(i, j)

      tbody.append('<td>' + x + '</td>');
      $('td').append(x);
    }
  }
  table.appendTo('#board2');
}
buildBricks2();

function indexOfTile(row, column) {
  var boardLen = 15;
  if (row < boardLen && row >= 0 && column < boardLen && column >= 0) {
    return row * boardLen + column;
  } else {
    return -1;
  }
};
```

```css
td {
  border: 1px solid black;
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-family: tahoma, arial;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="board2"></div>
```

Comment: Yes !! I just noticed that ... omg Im so dumb ....

Thanks for the quick reply !!!  have a great day/evening